# What is the significance of the plane tickets in Home Alone?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone

In the early scenes of *Home Alone*, much attention is drawn to some plane tickets:

- At least one goes in to the bin. The camera cuts so you can see this.
- Some have liquid spilled on them. The camera cuts so you can see this.
- Peter mentions, quite loudly, that he's putting some in the microwave to dry them out.

But do they have any impact on the plot? I feel like I've missed a key line or movement.

Comment: I think that the whole point is showing that it's absolute chaos at the McAllister house.

Comment: You may be interested in [*Home Alone: a Post-Incident Review*](https://ferd.ca/home-alone-a-post-incident-review.html)...

Comment: I also want to know what the McAllister brothers do for a living.  In the first film, the one brother flies all of these people to Paris for Christmas and in the 2nd film, Peter flies everyone to Florida for Christmas.  Seems like Uncle Frank is one brother who freeloads off the other two. lol

Comment: @Prem - In the novelisation and script they deal with the problem of the headcount by having a neighbour child get counted (outside the minibuses) and the problem of the extra ticket by having the passenger check-in officer flustered by the whole family turning up at the very last minute.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is because otherwise, if they showed up at the airport and still had Kevin's ticket, they would know instantly - upon checking in - that he was missing.

The fact that the ticket accidentally ends up in the bin neatly avoids this potential plot-hole, as well showing - as @steelersquirrel said - the chaos in the McAllister house.

Comment: Is there any scene showing the tickets being processed? I can't remember a check-in scene.

Comment: @J.Mini - as far as I remember there isn't, just one of them rushing through the airport.

Comment: You briefly see the gate attendant counting everyone at 0:36 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNWIR_-Vsiw

Comment: When-ever I see the "Pizza + Drinks Scene" , I always think that Director & Writer took great care with long set-up to ensure that "head-count" at van & at gate would work out. That was why the "Inquisitive Kid" was around near the van & that was why the ticket was thrown away !

Comment: @Prem The inquisitive kid gets counted as Kevin outside of the vans, but also there's supposed to be 15 family divided into the two vans. Each van has 7 and assumes the other is the van of 8 with Kevin.

Comment: Correct , more-over there is some miscounting due to diversions & divisions & lateness (at both locations) which are all in the elaborate set-up by Director & Writer , @StuperUser , which is great !

Comment: It also results in his sleeping alone in the attic.

Comment: Not to be confused with the scene where Kevin crashes into the gate attendant and the tickets go everywhere...how many times did they end up using these airline ticket plots anyway?  I only saw the first 2.

Comment: @rtaft In the third movie, the main character (not Kevin this time, was it Alex?) is staying at home with chicken pox, while his parents and siblings (including big sister Scarlett Johansson) are just at school and work all day. Actually an entirely ordinary situation.